# WinForms ReportViewer, line height is ignored

Tags: report-viewer2010

Does ReportViewer text box's line height property work? It seems to ignore any settings. What I want to achieve is to set line spacing for multiple lines of text.

Comment: Do you have CSS that might override this setting? I've had similar issues where settings appear not to work because I forgot the obvious fact that ReportViewer ports everything to HTML/CSS so your site css may mess with things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it ignores your settings because "LineHeight property setting only has an effect in HTML rendering".

You can check the same question on MSDN:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/af84ad88-f58f-44f3-b324-f2d5ca0ef9d8